# Python - How to do two or more function in one loop

Tags: python-2.7

Im trying to send files from a folder in ubuntu(Pictures) to (Downloads) after they have been processed using storescu.For each file processed by storescu I want it to delete that file.

So far I can do the storescu and then delete the file but I fear if more files come into that folder while it still processing the files it will just delete the files so I want it to process with storescu and then delete that file and move on to the next. Here is want I currently have:

```
import os, subprocess
src = "/home/pi/Pictures/"
dst = "/home/pi/Downloads/"
listOfFiles = os.listdir(src)
for f in listOfFiles:
        os.system("storescu /home/pi/Pictures/" +f)

listOfFiles = os.listdir(src)
for f in listOfFiles:
       fullPath = src + "/" + f
       subprocess.Popen("mv" + " " + fullPath + " " + dst,shell=True)
```

This is currently working but like I said it removes the files after it sends them all.

Comment: It seems like there must be something more to this that I don't understand. Why not just combine your two loops? Or even just get rid of the second `os.listdir` call, if you want to keep the two loops but have the second on only go over the same files as the first.

Comment: I want to combine them but when I did it keep giving me errors
>for F in listoffiles:
os.system()
fullpath = src + "/" + f
Subprocess.popen("mv" + " " + fullpath + " " + dst, shell=true)<
____
Result: indentationerror: Unindent dows not match any outer indentation level...
Sounds simple but Im new at coding

Comment: ok, Im an moron, one indentation was off by 2 spaces.... it works now. acK! thx.